# jq- Periodically add calculated values, based on exisiting values, to .json file

Tags: json, jq

There is an input file which contains several objects connected to one specific day. (In this case it's 4th of October). Each Object however, represents another time of that day, with different VALUES. "ID" and day are always the same in the file:

INPUT.json:

```
[
  {
    "DATE": "04.10.2017 10:20",
    "ID":"x",
    "VALUE_ONE": 20,
    "VALUE_TWO": 3
  },
  {
    "DATE": "04.10.2017 12:50",
    "ID":"x",
    "VALUE_ONE": 40,
    "VALUE_TWO": 5
  },
  {
    "DATE": "04.10.2017 14:20",
    "ID":"x",
    "VALUE_ONE": 10,
    "VALUE_TWO": 2
  }   
]
```

What I want to do now is calculate the day's total values and also do some math. (in this case either add or multiply by 3).

The results shall be added to the 'consolidated.json' file, which should contain one object for each day. To ensure that, this process will be repeated daily.

I have commented the calculation steps behind '//' :

CONSOLIDATED.json:

```
[
  {
    "DATE": "02.10.2017",
    "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 40,
    "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 800,
    "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 5,
    "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 110
  },
  {
    "DATE": "03.10.2017",
    "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 90,
    "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 890, // =800+90
    "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 8,
    "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 134 // = 110 + 3*8
  },
  {           //this object is new!
    "DATE": "04.10.2017",
    "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 70,
    "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 960, // =890+70
    "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 10,
    "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 164 // =134 +3*10
  }
]
```

I know I can get the totals of INPUT.json with

```
[.[]|.VALUE_ONE]|add
```

and

```
[.[]|.VALUE_TWO*3]|add
```

But I am not sure how to get this into the desired structure and use last day's totals. 
Thanks!

Comment: unclear how `"VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 164` was calculated?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build up cumulative sums of each of the values for each day. How are you determining the starting sum? Is it just defined as `VALUE_ONE[0] = 800` or was that just from previous invocations? jq could do this calculation alone... if it started from 0.

Comment: It would help considerably if you would clarify a few details.  Are the specific computations between the VALUES_ keys fixed?  Can some `input.json` introduce new previously unseen values?  Is the use of VALUE_TWO in `input.json` and VALUE_THREE_... in `consolidated.json` intentional or a mistake?  I.e. why are VALUE_TWO and VALUE_THREE_... keys related when VALUE_ONE keys appear not to be?  What if any precautions need to be taken with regard to the ordering and possible accidental reprocessing of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

jq -M --argfile i input.json '

    def VALUE_keys: keys[] | select(startswith("VALUE"));
    def TODAY_keys: keys[] | select(endswith("TODAY"));
    def TODAY_($k): "\($k)_TODAY";
    def TOTAL_($k): "\($k)_TOTAL";

    def new_totals: 
        $i
      | (map(VALUE_keys)|unique) as $attrs
      | reduce (.[]|.DATE |= .[:10]) as $d ({}
        ; reduce $attrs[] as $a (.
          ; [$d.DATE, $a] as $p | setpath($p; getpath($p)+$d[$a])
          )
        )
      | keys[] as $date 
      | [$date, .[$date]] ;

    def aggregate($k; $total):
        .[TODAY_($k)] = $total
      | if $k == "VALUE_THREE" 
        then .[TOTAL_($k)] += $total * 3
        else .[TOTAL_($k)] += $total
        end ;

    def next_day:
        foreach new_totals as [$date, $totals] (
           max_by(.DATE) 
         ; if .DATE == $date then empty else . end
         | .DATE = $date
         | .[TODAY_keys] = 0 
         | reduce ($totals|keys[]) as $k (.; aggregate($k; $totals[$k]))
       )
    ;

    . + [next_day]


' consolidated.json | sponge consolidated.json
```

`new_totals` computes the `input.json` sums returning the date and an array of values.  From the sample data it produces:

```
[
  "04.10.2017",
  {
    "VALUE_ONE": 70,
    "VALUE_TWO": 10
  }
]
```

`next_day` applies these values to the latest entry of `consolidated.json`
returning a value for the next day.  E.g.

```
{
  "DATE": "04.10.2017",
  "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 70,
  "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 960,
  "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 0,
  "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 134,
  "VALUE_TWO_TODAY": 10,
  "VALUE_TWO_TOTAL": 10
}
```

Note that the example output is inconsistent with the sample `input.json` so
the values differ.

The script adds this to the input and uses `sponge` to update `consolidated.json` with the new data.  Note that the line

```
| if .DATE == $date then empty else . end
```

prevents it from adding the data for a new day if that day is already present.  This is unnecessary if other safeguards are in place.

Note also that `next_day` uses `foreach` to handle the situation where `input.json` contains data for more then one day.  For example if the first element of `input.json` were

```
{
   "DATE": "03.12.2017 10:20",
   "ID":"x",
   "VALUE_ONE": 20,
   "VALUE_TWO": 3
}
```

`next_day` would generate two entries:

```
{
  "DATE": "03.12.2017",
  "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 20,
  "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 910,
  "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 0,
  "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 134,
  "VALUE_TWO_TODAY": 3,
  "VALUE_TWO_TOTAL": 3
}
{
  "DATE": "04.10.2017",
  "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 50,
  "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 960,
  "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 0,
  "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 134,
  "VALUE_TWO_TODAY": 7,
  "VALUE_TWO_TOTAL": 10
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTbbtpAEH33V0wdS9gFHHNTEyMqIREpldIiVbRV5VpowQs4wNrxrhtQzLfT9a5vBKgfYLx75syZMwMzRFdHPF8FUHPe1NFw8qDaqtU1W5bZtlqfoGXZbUttqF9G/HzHg5/Dpx8P0/E3jmtb@evk11i1O4fGRYa23bvG0D1l6F1h6F7X0DplaB/cGnwGn4QxM59pQJSz3to5b5VoOhmPhr@rguThZPik2ndWWeTx@0MB7r0/FehWy6q20flfufuL5e4vl7u7XK7TlT3PA0KDje8hhj3R@vHmw@3MJ7czPmJFeX6B5ldoNlG0XPgbDH7FJKgpCvDHwwuQJdZ4T21IPx0XEqB4g@dMpwxFjL76bKVLKaph9ItMIfNKJiZeliebOc/TtbVhg/on/c46rkJ4r@8hafv9UjjBr1MWMLTh5cVh@mh@Fiagb1Gol90ZSUz8lxgbgChoiLGIFtAIe/Ecg246bmKmg4RkAKbDl82VcA/0t0NRpJ8nSBret6Dk@QUkBTmaJ8ga/E5CQmEQCxE3Rgv7sCxio655DocZFYYyNgqlmc9CEx88FBeOeG9w1SJwXahYhZbLCC/5MXeyD5pwzbALetMpR@LCIAMU1P4CtDUMBlBdR7X0nK0wERz5zFyo5yTwEToFEG8ovgYsQcQDuQiVSe/Y1EP7UvEiiDCaryo7kFqSeyAZqQt6xU3Yot10ttfFSIxSPR8Ub1BOnfcobRUt4W3I9pnoVFaZkuR4CT@5cMqfReqlBdXbfNEyhYkcp9yxNd@f/sVRUUdbu0axDjKQ4zWhDk7uj6sotfO/BbhJty4MyBJfuAR@PQ@2W0z4EQQxA@oTLpH5gRnFBLwAUyABgxX6izOa4/Ef)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward solution, which for simplicity of exposition makes the following (easy-to-work-around) assumptions:

- The contents of input.json are as advertised, and in particular, that the date of objects in input.json does not yet occur in consolidated.json;
- The last entry in the array in consolidated.json has the most recent date, and that it is prior to the date of the entries in input.json

#### consolidate.jq

```
def aggregate:
  {DATE: (.[0]|.DATE|split(" ")[0]),
   VALUE_ONE_TODAY: (map(.VALUE_ONE) | add),
   VALUE_TWO_TODAY: (map(.VALUE_TWO) | add)}
  ;

.[-1] as $previous
| ($i | aggregate
   | {DATE,
      VALUE_ONE_TODAY,
      VALUE_ONE_TOTAL : ($previous.VALUE_ONE_TOTAL + .VALUE_ONE_TODAY),
      VALUE_THREE_TODAY : ($previous.VALUE_TWO_TOTAL + .VALUE_TWO_TODAY) }
   |  .VALUE_THREE_TOTAL = ($previous.VALUE_THREE_TOTAL + 3 * .VALUE_THREE_TODAY) ) as $today
| . + [$today]
```

#### Invocation

```
jq -f consolidate.jq --argfile i input.json consolidated.json
```

If you are sure it is safe to do so, you could tack on: `| sponge consolidated.json`

#### Output

The added entry is as requested, namely:

```
{
  "DATE": "04.10.2017",
  "VALUE_ONE_TODAY": 70,
  "VALUE_ONE_TOTAL": 960,
  "VALUE_THREE_TODAY": 10,
  "VALUE_THREE_TOTAL": 164
}
```